# Factorial hidden markov model using hmmlearn in Python

Tags: python, hidden-markov-models, hmmlearn

I am trying to find a way to implement Factorial Hidden Markov Model (FHMM) in Python using the package hmmlearn made for signal Hidden Markov Model (HMM).

I have tried to find a package that does but the ones I found either didn't work or were not available.

Is there any simple way to do it from hmmlearm ? or it would be too complicated ? $

I am still learning about HMM and FHMM so I might not have all the required background yet, so if ever you know a good reference and/or step by step tutorial that explains it, feel free to mention it.

Thanks !

I tried to use NILMTK package but it seems like there are a lot of installation problems.

Comment: please check this:
https://medium.com/@erdal.genc09/factorial-hidden-markov-model-for-time-series-analysis-in-python-4c6d6f33860b